# Amp Html Form Submition

Tags: html, amp-html

I am new in amphtml.I want to submit a form in amp Html,with input type="file" in localhost.How can I proceed?when the input type="text" it is perfectly running.but in input type=" file",it generates error.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using method="GET", `<input type="file" />` does not work with method="get", you have to use method="post" and attribute action-xhr in place of action.

[For example you can check here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KebdZa)

**JS CODE**

```
<script async custom-element="amp-form" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-form-0.1.js"></script>
```

**HTML CODE:**

```
 <form method="post"
  action-xhr="where-you-want-submit"
  target="_top">
  <p>Form Submission with Page Reload</p>
  <div class="ampstart-input inline-block relative mb3">
    <input type="file" name="any_name">
  </div>
  <input type="submit"
    value="Submit"
    class="ampstart-btn caps">
</form>
```

Comment: No I use,form method as post.and also use action-xhr.I noticed that,when I use a text input type,backend code returns header as application/json.but when I use input type as file,it returns header as text/html.